# How to group json data on the basis of the date in angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

What basically I am trying to do is that I have multiple json object, on the basis of the date data, I have to group data in the form of an array making the date filed as the key.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using few lodash function. The code is below `

```
 var temp1 = _.chain(res.data.events)
                    .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
                    .groupBy(function(o) {
                        return moment(o.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
                    }).value()
```

`

Comment: Strange! answwer and quesiton at the same time

Comment: @Sajeetharan this was something I wanted to share in question answer style